Change the order of the fields on the email notification sent from a task list after it is assigned?
How do i change the order of the fields on the email notification sent from a task list after it is assigned? I need to set the order of the fields in email notification

In Workflow add your table and value fields:
<table border="1"><tr><td colspan="2"><b>Created</td></b><td colspan="2">Created value</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><b>Date</td></b><td colspan="2">Date value</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><b>Modified</td></b><td colspan="2">Modified value</td></tr>
</table>

